Report Url in SharePoint Webpart loads to blank page
In summary, we have a BI report server where we host our reports (SSR/PBI).
We have a SharePoint directory/front page with a webpart that we are using to show a list of reports on that report server with a ".url" link for each report pointing back to the report server.
There are no issues with the reports loading on the report server (as expected) however the report link (.url) in the webpart on the SharePoint front page load to an empty page (about:blank) in Chrome/Edge on select.
The report will only load from the webpart when the ellipses > "open in app" is selected.  After the initial load of the report, the report link will then load on select but only by user.
How can we have the report load initially on a select (as opposed to "open in app").  What might we be missing?
